# Is there a web framework for a business listings website?

Tags: framework

Based on examples of specialized frameworks, such as Magento for e-commerce websites, is there a recommendation for a framework for a business listings website. Example of listings could be property listings.

Comment: Do you care about language? how about pricing/licensing?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out these parameters Nick. Do not care about the language. I would prefer an open source solution, but willing to consider anything really. Thanks.